# Selenium - How to Click a Link by href value in WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, onclick, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this piece of code

```
<a href="/iot/apply/device.do" id="subMenu1" class="fortification55"
                                                        onclick="$('#deviceinfo').hide()">Apply</a>
```

I am trying to link by href using

```
getDriver().findElement(By.name("subMenu1")).click();
```

But i got this error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with name == subMenu1 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Comment: I think  you should use `By.id("subMenu1")`

Comment: You can also directly use `getDriver().findElement(By.linkText("Apply")).click();`

Comment: you can also use xpaths: `//a[@id='subMenu1']` or `//a[text()='Apply']`

Comment: You can  use as : `getDriver().findElement(By.className("fortification55")).click();`

Answer (score 3):

As the element is having the [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) *Event*, the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element. So to invoke `click()` on the element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and only *href* attribute:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href='/iot/apply/device.do']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath* and only *href* attribute:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='/iot/apply/device.do' and text()='Apply']"))).click();
  ```
- Using a canonical *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.fortification55#subMenu1[href='/iot/apply/device.do']"))).click();
  ```
- Using a canonical *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='fortification55' and @id='subMenu1'][@href='/iot/apply/device.do' and text()='Apply']"))).click();
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on *NoSuchElementException* in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)
- [Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='login-email']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233)

Comment: @nice answer that should resolve the issue , and nice explination well done

Answer (score 0):

the following code should work :

```
By.xpath("//a[@href='/iot/apply/device.do']")
```