# How to click a button in an automated test using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

I'm trying to automate a test using Selenium and I want to click a button using xpath. This is what I'm doing:

```
WebElement LogInButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/login"));
LogInButton.click();
```

But I get an error that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/login"}
```

The only information I have about that button is this:

```
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

and the URL where it redirects to.
What am I doing wrong? What would be the correct way of referring to this button? Any help please let me know. Thanks

Comment: your xpath is looking for a tag "<login>".  You want to specify text or href.  Try with By.linkText("Login")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke `click()` on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *linkText*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/login']")).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/login' and text()='Login']")).click();
  ```

---

### Best practices

As you are invoking `click()` ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *linkText*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Login"))).click();
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href='/login']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='/login' and text()='Login']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)
- [Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='login-email']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233)

Comment: @iag20 Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.