# Selenium Fluent Wait Implementation in the code still gives "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:"

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

The mentioned URL in the code takes 5 seconds to display the login screen and in order to enter the details on the login page, I have implemented fluent wait for 10 seconds in my code. Even though the wait is correctly mentioned, for some reason this wait is not obeyed and i am always displayed with org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

CODE:

```
public class FluentWaitDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://app.hubspot.com/login");
        By email = By.xpath("//input[@type='email']");
        WebElement userId = FluentWaitForElement(driver, email);
        userId.sendKeys("*******@gmail.com");
        driver.close();
    }

    public static WebElement FluentWaitForElement(WebDriver driver, By locator)
    {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                              .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                              .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                              .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='email']"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Comment: if it takes 10 seconds to get that, the wait is working correctly.   I would just use a webdriverwait though...  it's a fluent-wait, too but is already setup with what you need... ignoring, polling, etc...

Comment: Any idea why the above code is still throwing no such element exception when everything is correctly mentioned.

Comment: it'll ignore for 10 seconds, does it happen before the 10 seconds is up or after?

Comment: No such element exception is thrown after 10 seconds. Ideally my code should suppress this message but still seeing no such element exception and because of this... I am unable to enter the email address on the login page. This scenario is perfectly handled by Webdriverwait but i want to understand what is wrong with my code having fluent wait.

Comment: assuming same XPATH, not sure what's happening... webdriverwait does set polling to 1/2 second though, so it's possible that at 8.5-9.5 seconds the option appears??  I would also try/catch the wait.until call to see if that's throwing timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* within the *Email address* field you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://app.hubspot.com/login");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#username"))).sendKeys("Bimlesh@gmail.com");
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://app.hubspot.com/login");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']"))).sendKeys("Bimlesh@gmail.com");
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: Hubsopt]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940) in:

- [Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233)