# Selenium: Element Not Found for existing element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have the following HTML Tag I want to fetch with Selenium:

```html
<button data-v-48e2f75a="" class="app-button rose-button min-width">Sign in</button>
```

I am trying to fetch it like so:

```java
...
browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("app-button rose-button min-width")).click();
```

When I run this it always returns the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: app-button rose-button min-width
```

This is one of the methods I've tried already however it has not worked either:

```java
browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("app-button rose-button min-width")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be By.className instead of cssSelector.

Example:

```
    WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.className("rose-button"));
```

If you want to use cssSelector, it should look like:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='app-button rose-button min-width']"));
```

Another way is using xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='app-button rose-button min-width']"));
```

And as DebanjanB mentioned, you can add webdriverwait also, if there is some kind of loading delay.

Comment: I can't believe I made such a mistake haha, always the small things that trip me up.

Answer (score 2):

The css selector is wrong. Try it in this way:

- browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(".app-button.rose-button.min-width")).click();

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Sign in** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.app-button.rose-button.min-width"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='app-button rose-button min-width' and text()='Sign in']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)
- [Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='login-email']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233)