# How to send the login credentials using HtmlUnitDriver and Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, nosuchelementexception, htmlunit-driver

I'm tring to send the login credentials within the username and password field https://www.vignanits.ac.in/server/moodle/login/index.php which needed to be automated using HtmlUnitDriver but facing NoSuchElementException.

Code trials:

```
package leela;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

public class LeelaHtmlUnit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
        driver.get("https://www.vignanits.ac.in/server/moodle/login/index.php");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()+driver.getTitle()); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("xyz");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xyz");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginbtn")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()+driver.getTitle());
    }

}
```

Comment: After you getting an error message?

Comment: @AnirudhTEAM You haven't told us where you are stuck. Your code works at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, to use [htmlunit-driver](/questions/tagged/htmlunit-driver) you need to download [**htmlunit-driver-2.42.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases/tag/2.42.0) the [latest release](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases) as of today.

The below code block works perfect at my end:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class HtmlUnitDriverDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.vignanits.ac.in/server/moodle/login/index.php");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()+driver.getTitle()); 
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("username")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xyz");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginbtn")).click();
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
https://www.vignanits.ac.in/server/moodle/login/index.phpVIGNAN MOODLE: Log in to the site
```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233) in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)