# Waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Could you kindly have a look at tell me why i cannot locate certain class that appears after i toggled the button.

1. click on toggle button and the sign up button should be enabled which it is.
2. then trying to locate the class associated with that button and click on it and it says it cannot locate it.

[image]

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys("test@test.com");
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("test");
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button-primary button-disabled']"));
chromeDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sign-up-row']")).get(1).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button-primary']")));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button-primary']"))).click();
```

or it does locate the class but element not interactble

```
 chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button-primary']"));
```

Comment: What is the error message? And what do you want to do with button-primary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below locator.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='button-hover-wrapper']//div[contains(text(), 'Sign up')]"))).click();
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button-primary']//div[contains(text(), 'Sign up')]"))).click();
```

Comment: thank you so much man, could you tell me maybe why it did not work previously when i was waiting for the element anyway

Comment: That happened because you are trying to click the `//div[@class='button button-primary']` element and i was receiving the click but the sub `div` that contains the `sign up` was not receiving the click to move further. If answered please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to wait for the invisibility of your progress animation and after that to find your element or wait for directly for the signup element

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sign up')]"))).click();
```

or use polling

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Sign up')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on <kbd>Sign up</kbd> instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.sign-up-row +p +div > div.button-inner"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button-primary']//div[@class='button-inner' and text()='Sign up']"))).click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)
- [Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='login-email']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233)