# Child of a parent node in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have searched through multiple questions like that but they don't seem to solve my problem.
I am writing an automated test and need to access a particular checkbox related to a text from several of them on the page.

```
<div _ngcontent-vcu-c32="" class="table-row-wraper ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-vcu-c32="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox center-absolute">
        <input _ngcontent-vcu-c32="" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="assign10000374">
        <label _ngcontent-vcu-c32="" class="custom-control-label" for="assign10000374"></label>
        </div>
      <ls-cross-api-lead-item _ngcontent-vcu-c32="" _nghost-vcu-c35="" class="ng-tns-c35-4">
        <div _ngcontent-vcu-c35="" class="table-row-border">
          <div _ngcontent-vcu-c35="" class="table-row table-row-min-height">
            <div _ngcontent-vcu-c35="" class="col-2">
              <span _ngcontent-vcu-c35="" class="d-block">Wednesday</span>
              <span _ngcontent-vcu-c35="" class="d-block">30.09.2020</span>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-vcu-c35="" class="col-2"> CREDIT </div>
      </ls-cross-api-lead-item>
    </div>
```

I need to find the /input of the checkbox based on the initial div containing text "CREDIT".
In my best knowledge this should do the work:

```
(xpath = "//ls-cross-api-lead-item//child::div//div[contains(text(), 'CREDIT')]//parent::div/div[@class='custom-checkbox']/input")
```

But it doesn't see the element to click.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

`//input[./parent::div/parent::div//div[contains(., 'CREDIT')]]`

Test: http://xpather.com/vklAaFbI

Answer (score 0):

To click on the input element `checkbox` based on the text `CREDIT` induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `elementToBeClickable`() and following `xpath` options.

**XPATH1:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement elementcheckbox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='table-row-wraper ng-star-inserted'][.//div[contains(.,'CREDIT')]]//input")));
elementcheckbox.click();
```

**XPATH2:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement elementcheckbox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='table-row-wraper ng-star-inserted'][.//div[contains(.,'CREDIT')]]//input[@class='custom-control-input']")));
elementcheckbox.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<input>` element with reference to the `<div>` element with text as **CREDIT** you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='CREDIT']//ancestor::ls-cross-api-lead-item//preceding::input")).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(., 'CREDIT')]//ancestor::ls-cross-api-lead-item//preceding::input")).click();
  ```

However, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='CREDIT']//ancestor::ls-cross-api-lead-item//preceding::input"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(., 'CREDIT')]//ancestor::ls-cross-api-lead-item//preceding::input"))).click();
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233) in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)