# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame while finding an element with in a modal dialog box using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to create a Selenium test, where a modal dialog is used. If I want to use the element in the div I get the error message that the element cannot be found. I have also tried to switch to the active element, or to switch to the frame. If I make this I get the error, that the frame cannot be found.

This is the html code:
[image]

This was my idea to switch to the modal:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div"));
```

And this is the error I got:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame:
> 805833b6-6961-41e5-8bdf-3393a28e0ad9

In the end I want to press the button inside the modal. I hope someone can help me to reach this with a selenium java test.

Comment: What do you get from: `List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagname("button"));
for (WebElement button: buttons) {
 System.out.println(button.getText());
}

WebElement modal = driver.findElement(By.className("modal-content"));
driver.switchTo().frame(modal);
List<WebElement> buttonsInModal = driver.findElements(By.tagname("button"));
for (WebElement button: buttonsInModal) {
 System.out.println(button.getText());
}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: 805833b6-6961-41e5-8bdf-3393a28e0ad9
```

...implies that the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you have identified as an `<iframe>` isn't an `<iframe>` actually.

From the HTML markup it seems the element is within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) and there are two buttons in it. To click on the two buttons you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- To click on <kbd>Weiter</kbd>

  - `cssSelector`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary[ng-show^='firstStep.state.spaces.length']"))).click();
    ```
  - `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and text()='Weiter']"))).click();
    ```
- To click on <kbd>Abbrechen</kbd>

  - `cssSelector`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default[data-dismiss='modal']"))).click();
    ```
  - `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default' and text()='Weiter']"))).click();
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233) in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly. Can you tell me also how to make this with a dropdown menu and with an input field ?

Comment: @tobias Sounds to be a completely different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: ok I will open today a new question with new source code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421606/selenium-find-select-and-input-in-dialog-modal this is my new question