# Unable to click or sendKeys in ajax overlay popup coming and its showing Element not Intractable exception using selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been practicing to automate few scenarios for web application way2Automation.com and struggling to enter the text in Registration form coming as the popup.
I have done some research already and tried many ways mentioned below:

a) Using WebDriverWait and explicit wait
b) Using Implicit wait and Thread.sleep
c) Using JavaScriptExecutor

But none of them worked for me and I am still stuck to register the user. Would really appreciate the help. Below are the artificats

URL: http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php

[image: way2atuomation]

Code trials:

1)

```
//  WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='load_form']/div/div[2]/input"));
//  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

2. 

```
//  WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"load_form\"]/div/div[2]/input"));
//  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(button));
```

Comment: I could not find the registration form where is that form or send link /url here ?

Comment: There is no registration form

Comment: Hey @JustinLambert: you can go directly to this link please to reach the registration form :  http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php

Comment: http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php    : To get the registration form in this website

Comment: @JustinLambert Can you help me with the base page of http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to handle windows
Try the below code and let me know updates

 driver.get("http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php");
        String parent=driver.getWindowHandle();
        String child=driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver).switchTo().window(child);
        driver.findElement(By.name("name")).sendKeys("Abhishek Saxena");
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a ton for the help. Since I was struggling in going through that. Can you please help with the fact that how you came to know to switch the window in this particular popup case ?

Comment: @JustinLambert `parent=driver.getWindowHandle()=child` still you need `switchTo()`?

Comment: @DebanjanB i am taking base page as parent and switch to child window that is registration page.

Answer (score 0):

To click on <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button[value='Submit']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='button' and @value='Submit']")).click();
  ```

However, as the element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.button[value='Submit']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='button' and @value='Submit']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233) in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)