# I am having problems identifying the element using selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am having problems trying to identify the element using selenium and java...for the following link:

```
<a id="newSearchNavigateHeadingEventId_0" class="search-heading" ng-href="book/event?eid=757231&amp;" target="_self" href="book/event?eid=757231&amp;">
<h2 ng-bind="event.EventDisplayName" class="ng-binding">Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction</h2>
</a>
```

I have tried the following ...

```
WebElement we = myDriver. findElement(By.linkText("Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction"));
WebElement we =  myDriver.findElement(By.id("newSearchNavigateHeadingEventId_0"));
WebElement we =  myDriver.findElement(By.xpath( " //a[@id='newSearchNavigateHeadingEventId_01']  "));
WebElement we =  myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction']"));
WebElement we =  myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='book/event?eid=757231&amp;']")) ;
```

But I keep getting the following message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: ....
```

Could some-one suggest what would be the correct path so that I can click on the link with:

```
we.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

To identify the element with text as **Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.search-heading[id^='newSearchNavigateHeadingEventId']>h2.ng-binding[ng-bind*=EventDisplayName]"));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='search-heading' and starts-with(@id, 'newSearchNavigateHeadingEventId')]/h2[contains(., 'Makerspace Docklands') and contains(@ng-bind, 'EventDisplayName')]"));
  ```

However, as the element is a dynamic element so to identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement we = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.search-heading[id^='newSearchNavigateHeadingEventId']>h2.ng-binding[ng-bind*=EventDisplayName]")));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement we = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='search-heading' and starts-with(@id, 'newSearchNavigateHeadingEventId')]/h2[contains(., 'Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction') and contains(@ng-bind, 'EventDisplayName')]")));
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233) in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you...
I found this also worked for me...

```
WebElement we = myDriver.findElement (By.xpath ("//*[contains(text(),'Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction')]"));
we.click();
```