# Selenium can't locate ANY element

Tags: java, html, selenium

So I have a webscraper which first of all needs to get past the cookie banner of a given website. Normally I'd just locate the element by id or classname and be done with it, but on [this site](https://www.schoolplaten.com/) none of the elements can be located. I've tried/checked the following:

- The element of interest is `<div id="cookiescript_accept" tabindex="0" role="button" data-cs-i18n-text="[]">Alles accepteren</div>`
- The element is not part of an iframe
- The element is not part of a shadow DOM
- Using `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` hits the 15 seconds timeout
- Using `driver.executeScript("return document.getElementById('cookiescript_accept');");` doesn't work either
- The parent element and parent of parent can also not be found

I'm still fairly new to Selenium and HTML so I must be missing something, please tell me if you know what that is

Code:

```
public void loadUrl(String url) {
    System.out.println("\t\t- loadUrl " + url);
    idle5000();

    driver.get(url);
    idle5000();

    setWindowSize();
    idle5000();
    printFirefoxCPU();

    scrollViewport();
    idle5000();
    printFirefoxCPU();
}
loadUrl("https://www.schoolplaten.com/");
prepRunnable.getDriver().findElement(By.id("cc-cookiescript_accept")).click();
//  -> NoSuchElementException
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(prepRunnable.getDriver(), 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("cookiescript_accept")));
//  -> Timeout
WebElement elem = (WebElement) prepRunnable.getDriver().executeScript("return document.getElementById('cookiescript_accept');");
elem.click();
//  -> elem is null
```

Comment: Show use your code.

Comment: has the element rendered on screen by the time your code executes? if not, the you should wait before you find the element, maybe try a classical sleep for 10 seconds and see the results?

Answer (score 0):

I could locate the web element with the below XPath

```
//*[name()='div' and @id='cookiescript_accept']
```

and could perform click on it with the help of below code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[name()='div' and @id='cookiescript_accept']"))).click();
```

Comment: For me this code has the same problem as all the other `wait.until` attempts, it hits the timeout and then the element still can't be found

Comment: Unbelievable, I used the exact code and it worked like a charm! You have to use this xpath `//*[name()='div' and @id='cookiescript_accept']`

Comment: `loadUrl("https://www.schoolplaten.com/");`
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);`
 `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[name()='div' and @id='cookiescript_accept']"))).click();`
This is literally what I'm running

Comment: what error did it throw up?

Comment: `TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[name()='div' and @id='cookiescript_accept'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`
and right after:
`NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[name()='div' and @id='cookiescript_accept'`

Comment: Well, if you could believe. The code that I have given you works for me well.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element <kbd>ALLES ACCEPTEREN</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#cookiescript_accept")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cookiescript_accept']")).click();
  ```

However, the element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#cookiescript_accept"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='cookiescript_accept']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also use the `executeScript()` as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#cookiescript_accept"))));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='cookiescript_accept']"))));
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202283/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to/46212233#46212233) in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: Unofrtunately, waiting until clickable gets to the 20 seconds timeout and then the element is again not found

Comment: Did you check the both the _xpath_ & _css_?

Comment: Yes I did, both to no avail

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: The alternative yields the same errors :s