# NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i would like to find my TextField in selenium, but i dont know how (i use sellenium for the first time).

I tried:

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("originTextField"))
```

or by xPath and cssSelector String generated by chrome in dev tools.

**Please help me, i would appreciate explanation.**

this is html:

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### NoSuchElementException

[**org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) popularly known as **NoSuchElementException** extends [org.openqa.selenium.NotFoundException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NotFoundException.html) which is a type of [WebDriverException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html).

*NoSuchElementException* can be thrown in 2 cases as follows :

- When using `WebDriver.findElement(By by)` :

  ```
  //example : WebElement my_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//my_xpath"));
  ```
- When using `WebElement.findElement(By by)` :

  ```
  //example : WebElement my_element = element.findElement(By.xpath("//my_xpath"));
  ```

As per the JavaDocs just like any other *WebDriverException*, *NoSuchElementException* should contain the following *Constant Fields* :

```
Constant Field      Type                                        Value
SESSION_ID          public static final java.lang.String        "Session ID"
e.g. (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.108)

DRIVER_INFO         public static final java.lang.String        "Driver info"
e.g. (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86)

BASE_SUPPORT_URL    protected static final java.lang.String     "http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/"
e.g. (For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html)
```

---

### Reason

The reason for *NoSuchElementException* can be either of the following :

- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted doesn't identifies any element in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted is unable to identify the element as it is not within the browser's [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted identifies the element but is invisible due to presence of the attribute **style="display: none;"**.
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted doesn't **uniquely** identifies the desired element in the *HTML DOM* and currently finds some other *hidden* / *invisible* element.
- The *WebElement* you are trying to locate is within an `<iframe>` tag.
- The *WebDriver* instance is looking out for the *WebElement* even before the element is present/visibile within the *HTML DOM*.

---

### Solution

The solution to address *NoSuchElementException* can be either of the following :

- Adopt a [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which uniquely identifies the desired *WebElement*. You can take help of the *Developer Tools* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>) and use *Element Inspector*.

  Here you will find a detailed discussion on [how to inspect element in selenium3.6 as firebug is not an option any more for FF 56?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-in-selenium3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-for-f/46702281#46702281)
- Use [**`executeScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method to scroll the element in to view as follows :

  ```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem);
  ```

  Here you will find a detailed discussion on [Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576958/scrolling-to-top-of-the-page-in-python-using-selenium/45581830#45581830)
- Incase element is having the attribute **style="display: none;"**, remove the attribute  through `executeScript()` method as follows :

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
  element.sendKeys("text_to_send");
  ```
- To check if the element is within an `<iframe>` traverse up the *HTML* to locate the respective `<iframe>` tag and `switchTo()` the desired *iframe* through either of the following methods :

  ```
  driver.switchTo().frame("frame_name");
  driver.switchTo().frame("frame_id");
  driver.switchTo().frame(1); // 1 represents frame index
  ```

  Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200).
- If the element is not *present*/*visible* in the *HTML DOM* immediately, induce [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) set to proper method as follows :

  - To wait for [**presenceOfElementLocated**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) :

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttonStyle']//input[@id='originTextField']")));
    ```
  - To wait for [**visibilityOfElementLocated**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) :

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttonStyle']//input[@id='originTextField']")));
    ```
  - To wait for [**elementToBeClickable**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) :

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttonStyle']//input[@id='originTextField']")));
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [python](/questions/tagged/python) client based relevant discussion in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you please  provide the equivalent for python for the `executeScript()` method ? Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, I suspect the issue caused the page not complete load when you find the element.

Try add a long sleep before find element,  if adding sleep worked, change sleep to wait.

Here is the code, It means waiting 10s if the element isn’t present:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "originTextField"))
)
```

Comment: or you can put `sleep(1000);`  and then `driver.findElement(By.id("originTextField"))`

Answer (score -2):

Below code will helps you get it resolved

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("originTextField")));
```

or

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)).wait(20);
```