# How to create Xpath for clickable text in Selenium Webdriver (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am working with this code code:[image]

I am trying to find text "Branch Selection" within a web page to click on it.

So I do this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Branch Selection')]").click()
```

It doesn't throw an error, but the click doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. If it clicks but nothing happens, first try adding a sleep like `sleep(5)` to help debug before clicking to see if its because Selenium thought the page loaded when it actually didn't finish loading. If you can click after sleep of 5 seconds then you need to use WebDriverWait and EC as @DebanjanB had shown. In worst case scenario you'll have to use a sleep in your code but try to get the sleep to as short as possible.
2. Otherwise you might have multiple elements on the page with `Branch Selection` text such as in the meta tags. Try using XPATH example below to isolate the XPATH look up:

`"//button[.//*[contains(text(), 'Branch Selection')]]"`

or if there's more than one phrase on page containing the text, use following to select exact text

`"//button[.//*[text()='Branch Selection']"`

This selects the button element that has a child element with the text you're looking for. More XPATH details here: https://devhints.io/xpath

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML provided to click on the element with text as **Branch Selection** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

- **CSS_SELECTOR** :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # lines of code
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.item.item-block.item-md div.input-wrapper>ion-label.label.label-md[id^=lbl-]"))).click()
  ```
- **XPATH** :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # lines of code
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='item item-block item-md']//div[@class='input-wrapper']/ion-label[@class='label label-md' and starts-with(@id,'lbl-') and contains(.,'Branch Selection')]"))).click()
  ```

Comment: I am trying to use the suggested Xpath method, and I get a TimeoutException error. Does it mean the Xpath is wrong?

Comment: @sprogissd Possibly I might have wrongly typed some tag/attribute while copying from the _HTML_  snapshot. A text based formatted _HTML_ would have helped. But that another aspect can be that the `xpath` derived from the _HTML_ you provided may not be **unique** and we may require some more of the _outerHTML_

Comment: @sprogissd A _TimeoutException_ error indicates that the element was not found. Can you check this discussion once? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940