# Selenium WebDriver tests fail after Chromedriver/Node update

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver, chai

I have been using Selenium WebDriver with Chromedriver, Mocha, and Chai. I had been running Chromedriver version 2.33, but just updated to version 2.38. I also ran an update on node. Only after the update nearly all of my tests started failing.

The error I'm seeing is "NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:".

Has anyone else had a similar problem where their tests started failing after updating?

Comment: What version is your browser? Check: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads, to make sure you are on a supported version.

Comment: Check this discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940

Comment: @PixelEinstein I am using Chrome version 66, Chromedriver version 2.38, Node v.9.11.1, and Selenium v.3