# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement({name: 'q'}).sendKeys('webdriverjs');
driver.findElement({name: 'q'}).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.ENTER);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated({xpath: '//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a'}), 30000);
driver.findElement({xpath: '//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a'}).click();
```

Getting the following error:

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12148/devtools/browser/86604bd8-c770-4659-bdaf-0abbf4cd790c
>       (node:15596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a"}
>         (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
>           at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\SPal\webdriverjs\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:585:15)
>           at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\SPal\webdriverjs\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:533:13)
>           at Executor.execute (C:\Users\SPal\webdriverjs\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:468:26)
>           at 
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
>       (node:15596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>       (node:15596) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add HTML snippet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementExeption, selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element)

Comment: At `driver.findElement({xpath: '//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a'}).click();` line?