# Selenium:- Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am confused a lot here. i am unable to click on a button. Maybe it is on different frame. But as i tried to use switch statement i got an error that no such frame found. And if i directly run my code by clicking on the button them i get's an error:- Unable to locate element: //*[@id='dutch_popupBtn']

The HTML is:-

```
<div class="horiZontalScroll">
    <table class="table highlight makeGapTable buyerTable setHeightThTd scrollTableRow">
        <thead>
            <tr class="auctionTable prodActName">
                <th class="active_purchase"><strong>Product</strong> <small>Auction</small></th>
                <th class="active_purchase"><strong>Volume</strong><small>ID number</small></th>
                <th class="active_purchase"><strong>Starting Price</strong> <small>Minimum Price</small></th>
                <th class="active_purchase"><strong>Bids</strong> <small>Current Price</small> </th>
                <!--<th><strong>Bids/Bidders</strong></th>-->
                <th class="active_purchase"><strong>Duration</strong></th>
                <th class="active_purchase"><strong>Action</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="active_auctions" class="mCustomScrollbar _mCS_3 mCS_no_scrollbar">
            <div id="mCSB_3" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" tabindex="0">
                <div id="mCSB_3_container" class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">
                    <tr class="auctionTable rowHref prodActName" style="cursor: pointer;" id="auctionlistrow621" href="/buyer/auction/auctiondetail/id/621">

                        <td class="active_purchase">
                            <strong>360A iodide</strong>

                            <small style="font-size: 75%;">Dutch Auction</small>
                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase"> 12.000 fl oz <small style="font-size: 75%;">ID 621</small>
                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase"> 10.000 EUR/fl oz
                            <small>100 EUR/fl oz</small>
                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase">
                            <small class="">9.600 EUR/fl oz</small>

                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase">

                            <span class="duration_left" data-id="621" data-bind="11d 20h 8m <br></span>">11d 20h 8m
                            <br>
                            </span> <small>10.05.2018 22:10:54</small>
                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase actionIcons">

                            <a title="Place Bid" href="javascript:void(0)" id="dutch_popupBtn" data-bind="621"><i class="fa fa-gavel" noredirect="1"></i></a>
                            <i title="Remove Auction" class="fa fa-remove no auctionDeleteBtnClass" data-bind="621" noredirect="1"></i>
                            <a title="Contact Seller" href="javascript:void(0)" id="requestQues" data-params="{&quot;userid&quot;:&quot;343&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Beta Zero&quot;,&quot;company&quot;:&quot;Clavax Zer0&quot;,&quot;membership&quot;:&quot;4&quot;,&quot;companyrevenue&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" data-auction="621"><i class="fa fa-envelope no" noredirect="1"></i></a>
                            <a title="Click to learn more" href="javascript:void(0);" data="dutch" class="tour_popupBtn" noredirect="1"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" noredirect="1"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="auctionTable rowHref prodActName" style="cursor: pointer;" id="auctionlistrow615" href="/buyer/auction/auctiondetail/id/615">

                        <td class="active_purchase">
                            <strong>360A iodide</strong>

                            <small style="font-size: 75%;">Dutch Auction</small>
                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase"> 12.000 Liter <small style="font-size: 75%;">ID 615</small>
                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase"> 5.000 USD/Liter
                            <small>1.000 USD/Liter</small>
                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase">
                            <small class="">4.900 USD/Liter</small>

                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase">

                            <span class="duration_left" data-id="615" data-bind="4d 18h 40m <br></span>">4d 18h 40m
                            <br>
                            </span> <small>03.05.2018 20:42:57</small>
                        </td>

                        <td class="active_purchase actionIcons">

                            <a title="Place Bid" href="javascript:void(0)" id="dutch_popupBtn" data-bind="615"><i class="fa fa-gavel" noredirect="1"></i></a>
                            <i title="Remove Auction" class="fa fa-remove no auctionDeleteBtnClass" data-bind="615" noredirect="1"></i>
                            <a title="Contact Seller" href="javascript:void(0)" id="requestQues" data-params="{&quot;userid&quot;:&quot;343&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Beta Zero&quot;,&quot;company&quot;:&quot;Clavax Zer0&quot;,&quot;membership&quot;:&quot;4&quot;,&quot;companyrevenue&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" data-auction="615"><i class="fa fa-envelope no" noredirect="1"></i></a>
                            <a title="Click to learn more" href="javascript:void(0);" data="dutch" class="tour_popupBtn" noredirect="1"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" noredirect="1"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </div>
                <div id="mCSB_3_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_3_scrollbar mCS-light mCSB_scrollTools_vertical" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
                        <div id="mCSB_3_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; height: 0px; top: 0px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                            <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My code is :-

```
//driver.switchTo().frame("active_auctions");  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dutch_popupBtn']")).click();
System.out.println("test");
```

The Error is :-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='dutch_popupBtn']
```

Can anyone help me in clicking on the Place bid button.
It would be very helpful.

Comment: I see two elements with same id (dutch_popupBtn). Please share which one you wanna select and click on it.

Comment: I want to click on the First one..
Can u please explain me how to click in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML you have shared and your code attempts I dont see any *frame* present by the *name/id* as **active_auctions** but to locate the element with `id` as **dutch_popupBtn** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='active_purchase actionIcons']//a[@id='dutch_popupBtn' and @title='Place Bid']/i"))).click();
```

---

### Update

As per your comment update as you are finding that *the focus is on the element but not clicking* you can use the `executeScript()` method as follows :

```
WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='active_purchase actionIcons']//a[@id='dutch_popupBtn' and @title='Place Bid']/i")));
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", myElement)
```

Comment: Ohh God..
U r good.. U have solved my problems a couple of times.. Thanks a lot..

BUT CAN U PLEASE EXPLAIN ME WHY HERE IT WAS NOT JUST STRAIGHT ND SIMPLE...??

Comment: @RAHUL Incase of _NoSuchElementExeption_ refer this discussion [NoSuchElementExeption, selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: the code has stopped working now..
It worked for the first time but not working now... The focus is on the button but not clicking to open the form...

Comment: @RAHUL Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: the code is working fine on refreshing the page by driver.navigate().refresh(); else it isn't reading the line..

new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='active_purchase actionIcons']//a[@id='dutch_popupBtn' and @title='Place Bid']/i"))).click();


Why it is so?

Comment: I would say instead of fixing through `refresh()` use the second option using `execute_script()` method.