# Using Selenium 1.82 By.xpath in xml view thows NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I had used sapui5 with xml view and java project, using Selenium 1.82 for automated testing.  When I used By.xpath , NoSuchElementException occurred. I have tried By.xpath(“//*[text()[contains(., ‘”+  父母 +”’)]]” and By.xpath(“//*contains(@text, ‘”+父母+”’))”) , the same exception happened.
How should I do?  Would anybody give advised will be deeply appreciated.

Relation.view.xml

```
<Select id=”relationSelect” selectedKey=”{Page>relation}”>
<item> 
<core:Item key=”1” text=”請選擇”/>
<core:Item key=”2” text=”父母”/> 
<core:Item key=”3” text=”配偶”/>
</item>
</Select>
```

Test script (driver had been instanced)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement  e =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[text()=’”+ “父母” +”’]”);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elememtToBeClickable(e));
e.click();
```

I also tried By.id(“relationSelect”), got the same exception.
The code By.xpath("//[*text()='"+ "父母"+"']"); worked during March 26 between April 17 this year. After the day (April 17th), when I restart run auto testing on May 2 it failed.

Comment: You've defined the explicit wait but you are finding the element before it !

Comment: Why can not use findElement before the explicit definition wait?

Comment: what do you think explicit wait meant for ? It is defined for any condition to become available either waiting after its visibility, presence , invisibility, element selection and so on,

Comment: I have already fix this problem by using implicitly wait instead of explicit wait.  driver.manage().timeouts.implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: that's a great news ! cheers !

Comment: @cruisepandey Thank you！

Answer (score 0):

Try this **code** :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement  e = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elememtToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[contains(text(),’”+ “父母” +”’]”)))));  
e.click();
```

Comment: It may be because of xpath . What kind of exception you are getting ?

Comment: NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text attribute set as **父母** you can use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//Select[@id='relationSelect']/item/core:Item[@key='2']"))).click();
```

Comment: I also already have tried your method,got the timeoutexception and nosuchelementexception.

Comment: To resolve `nosuchelementexception` follow the discussion [NoSuchElementExeption, selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Answer (score 0):

I have already fix this problem by using **implicitly** wait instead of **explicit** **wait**.

```
driver.manage().timeouts.implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```