# Find element in table using XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just started using selenium webdriver. I am trying to find an input field located in a table (can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1ZMt.jpg)

I've tried right clicking -> Copy -> Copy XPath, but when I start my program, i get the following error:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input"}
```

The input field I would like to find is the one called "loginanvid". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think your indexing may be wrong, try table[1], tr[2]. td[1], typically collections and arrays start with an index of zero

Comment: @RyanWilson No luck, unfortunately: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input"}

Comment: yeah, my bad. I just read that XPath begins at index 1

Comment: Could you post the actual string xpath you are using and not just the error message?

Comment: I've never worked with XPath before, so I just right clicked the "loginanvid" and pressed copy -> Copy XPath and got the following path: /html/body/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input

Comment: ok. thanks. Could you verify as cruisepandey said that the elements are not wrapped in iframe or frame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementExeption, selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element)

Comment: Post your extended HTML in the body of the question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kXiuw75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For switching to Iframe use this **code**:

```
IWebElement iframeEle = driver.FindElement(By.Name("main")); driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeEle);
```

then use this **Xpath** :

```
//tr[@class='bgmork']/descendant::input[@name='loginanvid']
```

Comment: Gives me the same error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tr[@class='bgmork']/descendant::input[@name='loginanvid']"}

Comment: please check if element is present in iframe

Comment: Because the pic you have provided , I can see the HTML and Body tags , most probably it would be in iframe

Comment: IWebElement iframeEle = driver.FindElement(By.Name("main"));  driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeEle);