# Selenium + WebDriver cssSelector not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

In Selenium WebDriver, findElement By `cssSelector` is not working or not accessible.

I'm trying to press a button. There are many buttons on the page, with same `id` and tags, automatically generated by the script of previous page. So I can't access it using `id` or any other tag. So I've decided to go for `cssSelector`.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


public class mrc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        System.out.flush();

        //Create firefoxDriver Object.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\eclipse\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        // LOGIN 

        driver.get("http://ec2#####-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/login");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("admin@admin.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/input")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/button[1]")).click();

        // JUDGEPANEL

        // Navigate to judgepanel
        driver.navigate().to("http://ec2#####-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/judgepanel");

        // select event
        Select drpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selector")));
        drpdwn.selectByValue("70");
        //drpdwn.selectByIndex(drpdwn.getOptions().size()-1);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/button")).click();

        // UPTO THIS PART IT WORKS FINE

        // enter scores
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button#disablerun.btn.btn-primary")).click();
        System.out.println("Button 1 Pressed");

    }

}
```

The error is:

```
    1525438082224   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1525438082242   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:39642
1525438083119   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\karan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.fUb9UrnMUqq8"
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1525438084292   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1525438086674   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 63161
1525438086758   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
May 04, 2018 6:18:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\karan\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
JavaScript warning: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript error: http://ec2#####-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/js/all.js, line 5831: TypeError: gapi.signin is undefined
JavaScript warning: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: button#disablerun.btn.btn-primary
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'KARAN-VAIO', ip: '*.*.*.*', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 59.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 1584, moz:profile: C:\Users\karan\AppData\Loca..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: b3b62974-ae5d-4885-956f-5ab2edf03dc9
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=button#disablerun.btn.btn-primary}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
    at mrc.main(mrc.java:51)
```

I've already tried xPath. It's not working too. How to resolve this error?

HTML for button is:

```
<div ng-if="!isLocked &amp;&amp; !Userlock" class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="entrance in entranceList">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 ng-binding">
Roma G
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<!--      run1 <input type="number" placeholder="Run 1 score" ng-model=entrance.run1> -->
run1 <b><span ng-bind="entrance.run1" class="ng-binding"></span></b>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<!--     run2 <input type="number" placeholder="Run 2 score" ng-model=entrance.run2> -->
run2 <b><span ng-bind="entrance.run2" class="ng-binding"></span></b>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<!--     <button class="button" ng-click=saveEntraceScore(entrance)> Save</button> -->
<button id="disablerun" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="EditEntraceScore(entrance)"> Edit
<!-- <div ng-if="isbattleTree === true" class="">
<i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div> -->
</button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Update the question with complete error stack trace and _Selenium Client_ / _WebDriver_ / _WebClient_ variant and versions

Comment: share the relevant HTML please

Comment: @DebanjanB Updated. Plz check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementExeption, selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element)

Comment: @DebanjanB Can you please explain me the error here. I didn't get anything out of it.

Comment: can you share the HTML for button#disablerun.btn.btn-primary ?

Comment: @KaranH.Joshi The error you are seeing is **NoSuchElementException** which is pretty common. Without your _Manual Steps_ and relevant _HTML_ it is a tough ask to analyze the error. Perhaps if you follow the dup marked discussion you would be able to overcome the issue.

Comment: @cruisepandey Added HTML portion

Comment: @KaranH.Joshi, check please my answer.

Comment: @KaranH.Joshi Are you trying to click on the `Edit` button?

Comment: Is this in an IFRAME? Your locator looks fine for the HTML you've posted. If you could post a link to the site, we could more easily figure it out.

Comment: @KaranH.Joshi, how is going? Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for that:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement edit_button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#disablerun.btn.btn-primary")));
edit_button.click();
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If this button is not in any **iframe** and ID of **disablerun** is unique , then this **code** should work for you :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("disablerun")));
driver.findElement(By.id("disablerun")).click();
```

If **ID** is not **unique** then you might wanna try this code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]")).click();
```

If it is in any Iframe then , first you have to switch the focus of webdriver to that particular Iframe using this code :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(WebElement args0);  
//then click on button
```