# Extract text br tags in selenium JAVA

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to get the texts 'Texas-United States' & 'Illinois-United States' so that I can click on the hyperlink placed above the text after string matches. I have tried following ways but couldn't get that. Can anyone help over here

```
findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/font/nobr")).getAttribute("innerHTML")
findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/font/nobr")).getAttribute("textContent")
findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/font/nobr")).getText()
findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/font/nobr/text()[preceding-sibling::br]")).getText()
findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/font/nobr/a[1]")).getText()
findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/font/nobr/a[1][following-sibling::node()[1][self::BR]]")).getAttribute("innerHTML")
```

HTML below for reference

```
<nobr>
    <a target="framedetail" href="DetailServlet?com=s&amp;cname=Bank%20of%20America%2c%20National%20Association" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;https://www.example.com/item1 this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">
        <img src="imgs/brcb.gif" width="8" height="8" alt="Commercial Bank" border="0">
        &nbsp;Bank of America, National Association
    </a>
    <br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Texas-United States
    <br>
    <a target="framedetail" href="DetailServlet?com=s&amp;cname=Bank%20of%20America%2c%20National%20Association" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;https://www.example.com/item2 this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">
        <img src="imgs/brcb.gif" width="8" height="8" alt="Commercial Bank" border="0">
        &nbsp;Bank of America, National Association
    </a>
    <br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Illinois-United States
    <br>
</nobr>
```

Comment: What is the exception are you getting?

Comment: for the above findelement lists, I could see the data but at times I get Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException' exception for findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/font/nobr/[following-sibling::node()"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to click on preceding link you can use below code:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//text()[contains(., 'Texas-United States')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]")).click()
```

and

```
findElement(By.xpath("//text()[contains(., 'Illinois-United States')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]")).click()
```

Comment: @Y5288 , Welcome! You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

To identify the the text **Texas-United States** and invoke `click()` on the hyperlink placed above the text you can use :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nobr//br[normalize-space()='Texas-United States']//preceding::a[1]")).click();
```

To identify the the text **Illinois-United States** and invoke `click()` on the hyperlink placed above the text you can use :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nobr//br[normalize-space()='Illinois-United States']//preceding::a[1]"))click();
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried it but I get Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException' exception.

Comment: @Y5288 To address _org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException_ check this discussion [NoSuchElementExeption, selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)