# How to click in nav-bar and choose item from a list in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried this

```
List <WebElement> navlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("d-md-down-none nav navbar-nav mr-auto"));
navlist.get(0).findElement(By.linkText("Sources")).click();
```

Below is the HTML code:

```
<ul class="d-md-down-none nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="px-3 nav-item">
        <a aria-disabled="false" href="#/sources" class="nav-link">Sources</a>
    </li>
    <li class="px-3 nav-item">
        <a aria-disabled="false" href="#/alerts" class="nav-link">Alerts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Error when trying my example :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at Adding_new_source.New_source.main(New_source.java:53)
```

How to click in nav-bar and choose item from a list in selenium java

Comment: Update the question with the result of your code trial and the error stack trace (if any)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at Adding_new_source.New_source.main(New_source.java:53)

Comment: You need to update the main question with this information for a proper analysis.

Comment: could you tell me the value of navlist .size()?

Comment: @cruisepandey ><body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden sidebar-removed">
        <div class="app"><header class="app-header navbar"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggler mobile-sidebar-toggler d-lg-none"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button> <a href="#/dashboard" class="navbar-brand active" target="_self"></a> <div class="navbar-toggler sidebar-toggler d-md-down-none" style="display: none;"></div> <button type="button"

Comment: @cruisepandey other part of html: class="navbar-toggler sidebar-toggler d-md-down-none"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

Comment: where is <ul> tag after these code ?

Comment: please print this code : navlist.size() and let me know the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because your CSS selector is incorrect. You have listed the class names but classes should be preceeded with a `.`, e.g. `.className`. The equivalent of your code would be

```
List <WebElement> navlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".d-md-down-none.nav.navbar-nav.mr-auto"));
navlist.get(0).findElement(By.linkText("Sources")).click();
```

Have you tried the simpler

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sources")).click();
```

It may or may not work depending on how many other "Sources" links there are on the page and where they are.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What error message do you get or what happens? What about the other way I posted?

Comment: What about the first method I posted? What was the result there? Are you sure that these elements aren't inside an `IFRAME`?

Comment: its in a plain html body no iframes, although before i get to this url there is another screen authentication which has a iframe, which i have already got into and now im coming out of it into this new HTML body but it has no iframes. i tried the first method its also gives me a "no such element error"

Comment: this is my code before i use your code just to give you context of the previous iframe> driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("duo_iframe")));;
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
   WebElement button = wait.until
   (ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector
     (".positive.auth-button[type='submit']")));
   button.click();

Comment: Did you ever execute `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`? That may be the issue. Add that code and any other details to your question so that everyone can see.

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have provided and your code trials you can choose and click an item with text as **Sources** from the *List* using the following code block :

```
List <WebElement> navlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.d-md-down-none.nav.navbar-nav.mr-auto li>a"));
for(WebElement elem:navlist)
    if(elem.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Sources"))
        {
            elem.click();
            break;
        }
```

Comment: tried the above, error message:no such element found.

Comment: For _no such element found_ see this discussion [NoSuchElementExeption, selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: i fixed my code, now i used the above code to try and target the specific "Source" element, in my console there is no error message so i did a print out of where its breaking and its breaking just after i insert the above code. "error on source selection"

Comment: When are you encountering `error on source selection` ? Did you click on the Dropdown for the `<ul>` to expand so you would be able to create the `List`?

Comment: yes i have, could it be that its because the list is also in a nav-bar?

Comment: <header class="app-header navbar"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggler mobile-sidebar-toggler d-lg-none"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button> <a

Comment: href="#/dashboard" class="navbar-brand active" target="_self"></a> <div class="navbar-toggler sidebar-toggler d-md-down-none" style="display: none;"></div> <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler sidebar-toggler d-md-down-none"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>