# Selenium Script pass in locally but fail on Jenkins while building

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

This is a very strange issue I am facing. I have my selenium scripts which work completely fine on my locally system when executed. Also I am using selenium grid for remote execution. When I try to run the same on my Jenkins which is installed on a VM my test fails. I have set my implicit timeout to 20 secs and page load timeout to 100 secs. Still I have the issue.

My Error logs on Jenkins for one of my failed test is:

Element not found exception.

Comment: 1) It’s possible that the app/page being tested loads a lot of JavaScript. Does your local browser always use the same profile or has static files already in cache? That might explain why local page loads are faster than when accessed from the Jenkins slave.

Comment: 2) Is there a difference in network latency between the client and the system under test in each case?

Comment: Hi timir, I am running on remote chrome browser. Only execution process changes. when I run in eclipse the test pass but when I run through my jenkins it fails. The browser is always the remote

Comment: Are you testing for images, or for some other element exist?

Comment: Yes the test for image. It failed for it and also I get  the element not found exceptions

Comment: In that case, consider taking a screenshot upon test failure.

Comment: I found the issue my test are executing faster on Jenkins VM. I think I need to add waits for it

Comment: @Jatin Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940