# NoSuchElementException with isDisplayed() method within try catch block in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i want to check negative condition.
above boolean element is not displayed ,but i have to print true and false but it shows no such element exception
please help.

```
try{

    boolean k= driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_element")).isDisplayed();
    if(!k==true)
    {
             System.out.println("true12"); 
    }

}catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Because driver.findElement is not able to find any such xpath and thus k is not assigned any value .before that NoSuchElementException is printed . You can confirm this via removing try catch block ...it will print the same exception again . You need to work on the xpath here or for some reasons it's not visible on page .

Comment: I know xpath is not available because radio button not available .but my testcase is to check if it is displaying print false

Comment: Add your driver.findElement section in try catch only . Your element will not be found and it will throw exception which you can catch and print message as per your testcase . No need to get values in Boolean k .in your case it not even executing if statement , it directly catching exception after first line

Comment: I added boolean and this verification inside catch exception ,now error not shown but not  displaying true or false                                                                 } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
  }
   boolean result = driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).isDisplayed();
   
   if (result==false)
  
    System.out.println("true12");
 }
  else {
   
   }
       System.out.println("false12");
  }

Answer (score 4):

There are two distinct stages of an *element* as follows:

- Element **present** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)
- Element **visible** i.e. **displayed** within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes)

As you are seeing [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940) which essentially indicates that the element is not **present** within the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and in all possible conditions **`isDisplayed()`** method will return **false**. So to validate both the conditions you can use the following solution:

```
try{
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_the_desired_element")).isDisplayed())
        System.out.println("Element is present and displayed");
    else
        System.out.println("Element is present but not displayed"); 
}catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("Element is not present, hence not displayed as well");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below code which will validate if at least one or more than one elements are present or not for the given xpath, before checking for the display status of the element.

```
List<WebElement> targetElement =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath_your_expected_element"));
    try {
        if(targetElement>=1) {
            if(targetElement.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Element is present");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Element is found, but hidden on the page");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Element not found on the page");
            }
        }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in finding the element:" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (driver.findElements(xpath_of_element).size() != 0) return true;
        return false;
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55426820/edit) some explanaion to your answer