# How do I wait for an element to be enabled before clicking on it in java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriverwait

Hi I'm very new to selenium and was wondering how it would be best to wait for an element to become enabled.  I'm writing a test to download a report that requires a status to be set at "Complete" within a table before a download button appears.  I have tried to use the isDisplayed() function but so far it fails.  I also need the timer to be dynamic to keep checking until the report is completed before downloading.

```
public static boolean isElementVisible(WebElement element) throws Exception {

    return element.isDisplayed();
}


public void statusCheck() throws Exception {


    if(Utils.isElementVisible(status)){

        downloadButton.click();
    }
    else{
        wait(100000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WaitDriver instead.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id1")),
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id2"))
));
```

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#or-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition

Answer (score 0):

A bit of more information regarding the elements, if *`wait for an element`* and *`status to be set at "Complete"`* refers to the same element or different element would have helped us to construct a canonical answer.

In case they both refers to the same [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) instead of validating with [`isDisplayed()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002843/nosuchelementexception-with-isdisplayed-method-within-try-catch-block-in-selen/51019309#51019309) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [`elementToBeClickable​(WebElement element)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
```

**Note**: There is no such method as `isElementVisible()` for *webelements*.

---

In case they both refers to different *WebElements* you can induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for both the [`elementToBeClickable​()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By)) using the `and` clause and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.and(
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("elementAcss")),
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("elementBxpath"))
));
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to wait for either of the two elements in the page using selenium xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166181/how-to-wait-for-either-of-the-two-elements-in-the-page-using-selenium-xpath/45170764#45170764)