# How to find button with selenium WebDriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I tried to perform click in my html page but it says unable to find the element.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btnStopSs" value="Stop" onclick="start_stop_Ss('tag_stopSs');">
```

Code:

```
IWebElement user = foxdriver.FindElement(By.Name("user_name"));
IWebElement pwd = foxdriver.FindElement(By.Name("user_passwd"));
user.Clear();
pwd.Clear();
user.SendKeys("admin");
pwd.SendKeys("admin");
IWebElement login = foxdriver.FindElement(By.Name("btnLOGIN"));
login.Click();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
IWebElement stopPage = foxdriver.FindElement(By.TagName("p"));
stopPage.Click();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
IWebElement stoptab = foxdriver.FindElement(By.Id("submenuOnLeftArea0_1"));
stoptab.Click();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
IWebElement stopbtn = foxdriver.FindElement(By.Id("'btnStopSs"));   //=>> Error OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: #btnStopss'
stopbtn.Click();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
IWebElement startbtn = foxdriver.FindElement(By.Id("btnStartSs"));
stoptab.Click();
```

Comment: please add the full error message

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer   OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: #btnStopss'

Comment: already had a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer    actually i tried Xpath but that doesnt Work too  
can u tell why its not find that button? its so Clear to find with ID...

Comment: is the button already on the page when you try to find it?

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer yes it is in the page fully loaded i can find another controls like textBox and other buttons but this one cant be find i dont know why

Comment: can you provide more code.

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer  i'd add all of my project code on my Q have a look at them ty.

Comment: can you also update your question with the full error message

Comment: already tried to find the element by value?

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer  how can i find the Element by Value can u give a Example Code? thanks a lot

Comment: little bit complicated but: `foxdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='button'][@value='Stop']"));`

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer  still got same Error ur code doesnt work its on my nerv :(

Comment: i still think that the button is not on the site when you come to the error line. This is the only explanation i can imagine. Is the button linked to the site?

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer  its in the page bro anyway thanks to u 
ill wait hope someone knows why its happen

Comment: if possible share link/url of page

Comment: @Dev here is the Webpage http://s8.picofile.com/file/8349429642/index2.htm.html  u have to download it its on upload center click on "دریافت لینک دانلود" then "دانلود فایل " to download it ty

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an extra **`'`** character within the *Id* attribute you have used. Additionally the element seems to be a dynamic element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `Id`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(foxdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("btnStopSs"))).Click();
  ```
- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(foxdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input#btnStopSs[value='Stop']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(foxdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='btnStopSs' and @value='Stop']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: i tried these 3 ways none of these works i dont know what is wrong with this code

Comment: @awrashpk Can you update the question with the current error stacktrace for further analysis?

Comment: same error OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: #btnStopss'

Comment: @awrashpk Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: still nothing with ur codes never mind ty @DebanjanB