# Not able to enter data in the Text field

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to access user name (`id = "username"`) field and enter data, however I am getting:

> element not found exception.

HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" action="/users/validate" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" id="authenticity_token" value="ChCVv99e+eLzD4IYQvnyv/tdc9m6yWGi34gSmp6PsbuQIAwIhjhwmDbzsxzXn1GmvpYzA8vpHmkfZNMfIuLNYw==">
    <!-- username non-validatable -->
    <div id="username-form-group" class="form-group label-floating">
        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="user[user_name]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="" maxlength="50">
        <small><a class="pull-right" href="/username">Forgot username?</a></small>
    </div>  
</form>
```

Using Selenium WebDriver and Java.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@method='post']//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

Looks like not able to switch in the form!

Comment: Please provide full html

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* within the *username* field, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("form[action='/users/validate'] label[for='username']"))).sendKeys("Manidipta");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form[@action='/users/validate']//label[@for='username']"))).sendKeys("Manidipta");
  ```

> Here you can find a detailed discussion on [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB. I did mistake, my page opened in a new tab however i was trying to locate in parent window. By default control stays in parent window, used window handler/iterator to navigate to child window and i was able to successfully enter value in user name field.