# Trouble generating the right Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

My requirement is when I click on Facebook it should open the Facebook homepage. The `xpath` which I generated is `//*[@class='sub2']/tbody/tr[2]/td/a` 
but still it is giving me `NoSuchElementException`. Please help me out in generating the correct xPath.

```
<div> 
<center>
<table width="100%" class="sub2" style="float: none" border='8' 
cellspacing="8" cellpadding="8">
<tbody>
          <tr>
             <th>
               <center>Sample Program</center>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="https://facebook.com">
            <center> Facebook </center>
            </a>
         </td>
         </tr>
          <tr> </tr>
       </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath's [normalize-space()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) as in `//a[normalize-space()="Facebook"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the element by using the xpath:

```
//a[@href='https://facebook.com']
```

Comment: I tried this option. It still gives me  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as **Facebook** you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  "table td>a[href*='facebook']>center"
  ```
- Using *Xpath*:

  ```
  "//table//td/a/center[normalize-space()='Facebook']"
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussions on *NoSuchElementException* in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: It is still giving me NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have messed up absolute xpath with relative xpath. if you start by using // it means you are using relative xpath. // means it can search the element anywhere at the webpage. Since you are trying to find a tag with the text 'Facebook' you can try `//a[contains(text(),"Facebook")]` which means select an anchor tag within the whole DOM which contains the text "Facebook". 
Or you can try `//*[contains(text(),"Facebook")]` if you are quite sure there are no other elements containing the text 'Facebook', since the above xpath means "select all elemnts in the DOM where it contains the text 'Facebook' ".