# Selenium java code runs test successfully but fails when run as headless

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, runtime-error, headless

My java selenium java test case with Chrome version 77 runs fine when `options.setHeadless(false);` but fails when I change this line `options.setHeadless(true);`

The java code was exported by the katalon selenium recorder chrome extension.

Output when it runs fine with `options.setHeadless(false);`:

```
Title of the page is 9 -> Scan History
Title of the page is 10 -> Scan History
Title of the page is 10.1 -> Scan History
Title of the page is 10.2 -> Scan History
Title of the page is 10.3 -> Scan History
Title of the page is 10.4 -> Scan History
Title of the page is 10.5 -> Scan History
```

When I run the same code with `options.setHeadless(true);` I get a below warning as well as an error message and the execution terminates before completion.

```
Title of the page is 10 -> Scan History
[0530/125542.102:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mod
e=block, 1;mode=block: expected semicolon at character position 13. The default
protections will be applied.", source: https://qualysguard.myshop.com/fo/scan/sca
nList.php (0)
Title of the page is 10.1 -> Scan History
Title of the page is 10.2 -> Scan History
Title of the page is 10.3 -> Scan History
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such e
lement: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#ext\-gen
117"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.75)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/except
ions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17
:03'
System info: host: 'myhostserver', ip: '10.9.111.32', os.name: 'Windows Serve
r 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 7
7.0.3865.75, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userD
ataDir: C:\Users\1886\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: l
ocalhost:56128}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageL
oadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRe
ct: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 30
0000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 09a309a747f7bcb42735bb8b6c39ad1f
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=ext-gen117}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(
W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpRe
sponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpRe
sponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExe
cutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(Driv
erCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDrive
r.java:323)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebD
river.java:372)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDrive
r.java:315)
        at pack.QualysScan.testQualysScan(QualysScan.java:182)
        at pack.QualysScan.main(QualysScan.java:284)
```

Here is the part of the code concerning the issue:

```
System.out.println("Title of the page is 10 -> " + driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("body-header")).click();
driver.get("https://qualysguard.myshop.com/fo/scan/scanList.php");
System.out.println("Title of the page is 10.1 -> " + driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Add to my Calendar'])[1]/following::em[2]")).click();
System.out.println("Title of the page is 10.2 -> " + driver.getTitle());
System.out.println("Title of the page is 10.3 -> " + driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen117")).click();
System.out.println("Title of the page is 10.4 -> " + driver.getTitle());
System.out.println("Title of the page is 10.5 -> " + driver.getTitle());
String your_title = "Launch Compliance Scan";
```

And here is how the driver is setup:

```
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "H:\\Downloads\\Qualys\\vdi\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options =  new ChromeOptions();
          options.setHeadless(true);
          DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
    options.merge(capabilities);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

I'm sharing snapshot of element `ext\-gen117` as visible on the portal.

[image]

[image]

Video of the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abSwsPtOOG4

Can you please suggest how can I overcome the issue?

Comment: When the test runs in headless mode, is it running from your computer or on another computer? Is this a public facing website or internal to your organization?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I connect to a VDI system, using VPN. From this VDI system, I'm connecting to internal website: Please have a look at the video demonstrating the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abSwsPtOOG4

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by a race condition between the browser and selenium, where selenium attempts to click on something before it exists in the DOM. Using an explicit wait should resolve the issue:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ext-gen117");
element.click();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error ` cannot find symbol symbol: variable TimeSpan` what library do I need to import? can you please guide?Note: I'm using JAVA 1.8

Comment: I simply removed TimeSpan and went for default like this `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 30);` I was able to compile and run but I'm again getting a different error for the same element as below: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id : ext-gen117 (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds  interval)`. Please suggest.

Comment: @Asher: Updated my answer. Sorry about that. I don't write much Java.

Comment: Hi @Grey The solution does not work and times out. Please look for the exception shared in my previous comment. Kindly suggest.

Comment: @Asher: you probably need to take a screenshot of the failure before we can help you further.

Comment: @Grey i will record a video and/or snapshot and share tomorrow.

Comment: please have a look. I recorded this video to demonstrate the issue: https://youtu.be/abSwsPtOOG4

Comment: @DebanjanB The suggestion did not help. Please have a look at the video demonstrating the issue and has your recommendations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abSwsPtOOG4

Comment: Should I repost (new post) in case this has lost attraction/attention?

Comment: If you are getting a different error, a new question would be beneficial.

Comment: I m getting the timeout error which I posted as a comment after implementation of the wait suggested here as an answer.

Comment: @Ashar [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940) is difficult to debug without the actual [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

Comment: @DebanjanB I understand that but why does it work when headless is set to false? Also, the element is visible using pathfinder chrome extension as shown in the snapshot for gen117

Comment: @Ashar Precisely the `headless` rendering process is different from the normal one at least for Chrome.

Comment: @DebanjanB I tried HTMLUNITDRIVER too but that too fails with a similar timeout. sadly I don't find any solution. Can you suggest some workaround or debugs that can help?

Comment: @DebanjanB how can I get the HTML DOM of my webpage to help debug further? I don't know how to get the HTML DOM. Please guide.