# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException errorusing Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

Below is the code I wrote in Java to perform a test which involves switching to windows handles.

```
package com.Practice;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Assignment4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\vikas\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@id='content']/ul)/li[33]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='windows']")).click();
        Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = windows.iterator();
        String parentId = it.next();
        String childId = it.next();
        driver.switchTo().window(childId);
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'New Window')]")).getText());
        driver.switchTo().window(parentId);
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/h3")).getText());
    }

}
```

To the best of my knowledge I assume this code is correct but still I am facing error. I am facing no such element exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:760)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:780)
    at com.Practice.Assignment4.main(Assignment4.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

...implies that [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940) was raised as no such element can be found using the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

To identify the element with text as **Multiple Windows** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@id='content']//ul//li[33]"))
  ```

---

Using a more canonical approach you can use:

- `linkText`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Multiple Windows"));
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/windows']"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Multiple Windows']"));
  ```