# NoSuchElementException on trying to pick select HTML tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am currently learning Selenium 4 and decided to write some code for the site: [Art Of Testing](https://artoftesting.com/samplesiteforselenium) using Java Bindings, TestNG and Firefox Driver. On the site, there is a dropdown list (select HTML element) with id **testingDropdown**. I am currently using the Page Object Factory and thus using **@FindBy** notation to get DOM elements. I am using **Select** object to work with the dropdown list. The code for which is as follows:

```
    @FindBy(tagName="select")
    private WebElement selectDropDown;
    
    private Select selectDropList;
    
    public PageObject(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        
        action = new Actions(driver);
        
        selectDropList = new Select(selectDropDown);

    }
```

The method to check this DOM is as follows:

```
 @Test
  public void checkDropDown() throws Exception {
      assertFalse(pageObj.isDropDownMultiple());
      assertEquals(pageObj.getDropDownSize(), 4);
      
      List<String> listOptions = new ArrayList<>();
      listOptions.add("Automation");
      listOptions.add("Performance");
      listOptions.add("Manual");
      listOptions.add("Database");
      
      for (int i = 0; i < listOptions.size(); i++) {
          String visibleText = listOptions.get(i) + " Testing";
          assertEquals(pageObj.selectDropDownItem(listOptions.get(i)), visibleText);
      }
  }
```

My code fails with the `NoSuchElementFoundException: select`. I have tried the following but the exception still remains:

1. Change the Find notation to use `id="testingDropdown"`.
2. Change the Find notation to use `xpath=//*[@id="testingDropdown"]`.
3. Excluding the test `checkDropDown` using the exclude tag in TestNGSuite.xml .
4. Commenting out the `checkDropDown` method in my test file.
5. Center the dropdown list in the method `isDropDownMultiple` with the following:

   public boolean isDropDownMultiple() {
   // Center the dropdown list
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", selectDropList);
   return selectDropList.isMultiple();
   }

To verify that the element exists, I have tried the following code in the Dev Tools of Firefox:

```
var s = document.getElementById("testingDropdown");
console.log(s.innerHTML);
```

and got the following result, proving that the element exists and is visible:

```
<option id="automation" value="Automation">Automation Testing</option><option id="performance" value="Performance">Performance Testing</option><option id="manual" value="Manual">Manual Testing</option><option id="database" value="Database">Database Testing</option>
```

From [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element), I have tried centering the element, I am using `implicitWait` with a duration of 20 seconds. With this timeframe and 11 other tests before the dropdown one, the page is fully loaded.

All tests are skipped because of this exception. If I comment out the `WebElement` and `Select` objects, only then the test file executes.

So, I am stuck and don't know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. As can be seen from the constructor code, `Select` object was built when the page was not even loaded. Hence, there was no DOM elements with the id. Created another method and called that at the start of the `checkDropDown` method to initialize the `Select` object and also do a `findElement(By.id('testingDropdown')` to build the `WebElement`. Now, the test case executed and everything is good!